# Heap Memory Issues on Java

Tags: java, csv, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am trying to run the program below but I get the OutOfMemory error during the StringBuilder appending loop structure.

1. I am trying to do anything to lower the memory usage just enough to be able to read a CSV file (over 200,000 rows but only 3 columns:item,rating,user).
2. I would then create a 2D int array in which unique items represent
   the rows, unique users represent the columns and the intersection is
   the rating.
3. Finally, I would use StringBuilder to help create the output CSV file

Thank you for your help and time.

```
      List<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();


      FileInputStream stream = null;
      Scanner scanner = null;
      int[][] layout = new int[10672][24303];

      int indexItemList = 0;
      double temp = 0;

      try{
         stream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
         scanner = new Scanner(stream, "UTF-8");
         while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
             String line = scanner.nextLine();
             if (!line.equals("")){
                String[] elems = line.split(",");
                if (indexItemList == 0) {
                    temp = Double.valueOf(elems[1]);
                  layout[0][0] = (int)temp;
                    itemList.add(elems[0]);
                    userList.add(elems[2]);
                    indexItemList++;
                }
                else {
                    boolean itemFound = itemList.contains(elems[0]);
                    boolean userFound = userList.contains(elems[2]);

                    int indexItem = 1;
                    int indexUser = 1;
                    if ((itemFound) && (userFound)) {
                        indexItem = itemList.indexOf(elems[0]);
                        indexUser = userList.indexOf(elems[2]);
                     temp = Double.valueOf(elems[1]);
                        layout[indexItem][indexUser] = (int)temp;
                    }                    
                    else if ((itemFound) && (!userFound)) {
                        userList.add(elems[2]);
                        indexItem = itemList.indexOf(elems[0]);
                        indexUser = userList.indexOf(elems[2]);
                     temp = Double.valueOf(elems[1]);
                        layout[indexItem][indexUser] = (int)temp;
                    }
                    else if ((!itemFound) && (userFound)){
                        itemList.clear();
                        itemList.add(elems[0]);
                        indexUser = userList.indexOf(elems[2]);
                     temp = Double.valueOf(elems[1]);
                        layout[indexItemList][indexUser] = (int)temp;
                        indexItemList++;
                    }
                    else if (!((itemFound) && (userFound))) {
                        itemList.clear();
                        itemList.add(elems[0]);
                        userList.add(elems[2]);
                        indexUser = userList.indexOf(elems[2]);
                     temp = Double.valueOf(elems[1]);
                        layout[indexItem][indexUser] = (int)temp;
                        indexItemList++;
                    }   
                }
             }
         } 
         if (scanner.ioException() != null){
            throw scanner.ioException();
         }
      }
      catch (IOException e){
         System.out.println(e);
      }
      finally{
         try{
            if (stream != null){
               stream.close();
            }
         }
         catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
         }
         if (scanner != null){
            scanner.close();
         }
      }

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      for (int i = 0; i < layout.length; i++){
          for (int j = 0; j < layout[i].length; j++){
             sb.append(layout[i][j] + "");
             layout[i][j] = 0;
             if (j < layout[i].length - 1){
                sb.append(",");
             }
          }
          sb.append("\n");
       }
```

Comment: It seams to me that you don't need that `StringBuilder`: you could just write directly into the output file.

Comment: What is the final CSV that you need? Are you trying to write out a value for every unique user/item combination? To reduce memory footprint of the stringbuilder, write out to file frequently instead of trying to hold the entire csv in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Your file has 200'000 rows, but your 2D array has 259'361'616 cells, and the size of the `StringBuilder` will be proportional to that number. You don't need to store all this: it's a very hollow matrix.

Here's what I would do: while reading the input file, I would build two string sets: the items and the users, and a map associating the rating to each (item,user) couple:

```
    Set<String> items = new TreeSet<>();
    Set<String> users = new TreeSet<>();
    Map<String,Double> ratings = new HashMap<>();
    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream, "UTF-8")) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!line.equals("")) {
                String[] elems = line.split(",");
                String item = elems[0];
                String user = elems[2];
                double rating = Double.parseDouble(elems[1]);
                items.add(item);
                users.add(user);
                ratings.put(item+','+user, rating);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Note that I've used `TreeSet`s to ensure the elements are sorted, but if you don't care about this, you can use `HashSet`s instead. To keep the elements in order of appearance, as you seam to be doing in your code, you can use `LinkedHashSet`s.

You can then write to the output file like this:

```
    try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(outputName);
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer)) {
        for (String item: items) {
            int j = 0;
            for (String user: users) {
                Double rating = ratings.get(item+','+user);
                double r = rating == null ? 0 : rating;
                out.print(r);
                ++j;
                if (j < users.size()) {
                    out.print(',');
                }
            }
            out.println();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

UPDATE:

In the case where you have more than one rating for the same (item,user) couple, you only keep the last one. You could calculate the average by using `Accumulator`s instead of `Double`s in your map:

```
public class Accumulator {
    private int count;
    private double sum;

    public void add(double value) {
        sum += value;
        ++count;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return count == 0 ? 0 : sum/count;
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2: Errata

The size of the `StringBuilder` is not proportional to the size of the matrix, but to the number of items times the number of users.

Answer (score 0):

[The Structure of the Matrix I Am Trying to Create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aDnX.png)

The original CSV file that I am parsing through is over 200,000 rows with exactly 3 columns (user,rating,item). I was hoping to create a matrix resembling the attached photo. The reason is I was planning to use this matrix later on for my method of calculating the cosine similarity between two matrix rows (which would be the input of the method). Basically, I would compare all the ratings of the first row (userID #1) with the ratings of the second row (userID #2).